# Admin Order Creation: How to Remove or Skip Store Selection step and Set Default Store View Programmatically?

Tags: store-view, admin-order-create

I am seeking assistance with a specific task related to the admin order creation page in our system. Currently, the process involves navigating to
Sales -> Orders -> Create new order -> Select the customer.

[image]

http://domainame.com/admin/sales/order_create/index/

However, I am looking to streamline this process by eliminating the store selection step. Our application operates with a single 'default store view,' and I would like to set this programmatically.

Any guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

**app/code/Vendor/Sales/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form">
        <plugin name="set_default_store_id_for_new_order" type="Vendor\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Form.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create;

use Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form as BaseForm;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;

class Form
{
    /**
     * @param Json $json
     */
    public function __construct(
        private Json $json
    ) {

    }

    /**
     * @param BaseForm $subject
     * @param $data
     * @return bool|string
     */
    public function afterGetOrderDataJson(
        BaseForm $subject,
        $data
    ) {
        $data = $this->json->unserialize($data);
        $data['store_id'] = 1;
        return $this->json->serialize($data);
    }
}
```